# ¿Cómo puedo llamar 2 métodos a la vez dentro de un evento onChange?

Tags: reactjs

Quiero realizar dos eventos dentro de un input, como puedo llamar a los dos de manera continua o como tendría que declarar el método? Yo traté de la siguiente forma pero me arroja error, podrían darme alguna sugerencia?

**mi entrada**

```
<input style={styles.input} placeholder='Introduce tu nombre' type='text'
        name={this.state.nombre} onChange={this.bChange, this.hChange}>
```

**y los eventos**

```
hChange(e) {const name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({input:name});
    this.props.cambioNombre(name);  }

bChange(e) {const letras= e.target.value;
    if(letras >= 4) {
      this.setState({habilitado:false});
    } else if (!this.state.habilitado) {
      this.setState({habilitado:true});
  } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de utilizar **React.js** puedes hacerlo así:

```
<input onChange={ () => { this.bChange(); this.hChange(); } }>
```

En caso de **Vanilla JavaScript** puedes hacerlo así:

```
<input onchange="bChange(), hChange()">
```

Comment: Gracias Denis ! me sirvio perfecto, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

separa las funciones en el `onChange` con `;` para que se ejecuten al tiempo de cumplir con el evento.

```js
function a(){

console.log('hola');

}

function b(){

console.log('hola2');

}
```

```html
<input placeholder='Introduce tu nombre' type='text'
        name="name" onChange="a();b()">
```

Comment: Gracias por sus respues, actualmente me encuentro trabajando con React! les agradezco el apoyo a todos !